# Moodle module no database

Tags: php, database, module, moodle

I want to develop a **module** for Moodle 2.0 that **doesn't need database**.

How should I fill the **install.xml** file when I will not have tables in the database?

Thanks for the help.

Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a need for a database then you don't need to have an `install.xml` file at all. Moodle will still happily install a plugin without one.

Remember, if you do want a table within the database, the best method for creating that file is using:

*Site Administration* -> *Development* -> *XMLDB editor*

This presents you with a relatively easy to use UI and ensures that Moodle will be happy with your XML.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create db folder in plugin.